# How to save these randomly generated items

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to make a simple little ASCII-RPG game.

I'm currently trying to implement a mechanic that will allow a random village to be generated and then added as an input-able option on the "map". So whatever iteration you initially generate for the village would be saved and added to the "map" and then allow the user to return to it rather than simply generate a new village iteration.

For example:

```cs
class Program
{
    Villages randVillages = new Villages();
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool exitMap = false;
        while (exitMap == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is your map");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("1) Search for a new location");

            string newLocation = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            if (newLocation == "1")
            {
                {
                    Villages.StandardVillage();
                }
            }
            if (newLocation == "2")
            {
                exitMap = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
class Villages
{
    public static void StandardVillage()
    {
        int setLandscape;
        Random randVillage = new Random();
        setLandscape = randVillage.Next(1, 5);

        if (setLandscape == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("       (________________)");
            Console.WriteLine("        |              |");
            Console.WriteLine("        |  []  []  []  |");
            Console.WriteLine(" _______|____          |");
            Console.WriteLine(" |          |  []  []  |       ");
            Console.WriteLine(" | { }  { } |          |    _I_____");
            Console.WriteLine(" |          |  []  []  |   /_______\\");
            Console.WriteLine(" | { }  { } |          |   | [] [] |");
            Console.WriteLine("_|          |  []  []  |___| [] [] |_");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        }
        if (setLandscape == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("               xXxXxXxXxXxXx ");
            Console.WriteLine("               |           | ");
            Console.WriteLine("               | |}{| |}{| | ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ____________  |           | ");
            Console.WriteLine(" |          |  | |}{| |}{| |     _I_____");
            Console.WriteLine(" |  []  []  |  |           |    /_______\\");
            Console.WriteLine(" |          |  | |}{| |}{| |  _ | [] [] |");
            Console.WriteLine("_|  []  []  |__|           |__|_| [] [] |_");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");
        }
        if (setLandscape == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("                {_{_{_{_}_}_}_}");
            Console.WriteLine("                /             \\");
            Console.WriteLine("               /_______________\\");
            Console.WriteLine("   _I_____     |               |");
            Console.WriteLine("  /_______\\    |  {} {} {} {}  |");
            Console.WriteLine("  | [] [] |    |               |  (__)");
            Console.WriteLine("xX| [] [] |Xx__|  {} {} {} {}  |___()_");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
        }
        if (setLandscape == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("                     {____________}");
            Console.WriteLine("                     |            |");
            Console.WriteLine(" __________________  | [}{]  [}{] |");
            Console.WriteLine(" |                |  |            |");
            Console.WriteLine(" | [] [] [] [] [] |  | [}{]  [}{] | ____");
            Console.WriteLine(" |                |  |            | |__|");
            Console.WriteLine("_| [] [] [] [] [] |__| [}{]  [}{] |_|  |");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
        }

        int setTool1;
        setTool1 = randVillage.Next(1, 3);

        if (setTool1 == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1) Speak to someone in charge");
        }
        if (setTool1 == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1) Ask about local rumors");
        }

        int setTool2;
        setTool2 = randVillage.Next(1, 3);
            
        if (setTool2 == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2) Go to the local guild hall");
        }
        if (setTool2 == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2) Go to the local tavern");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("0) Exit to map");

        string villageOptions = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        if (villageOptions == "1" && setTool1 == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The elderman of the village greets you cheerily.");
        }
        if (villageOptions == "1" && setTool1 == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A local indulges you.");
            Console.WriteLine("\"I hear the local tavern cooks a mean birdpie.\"");
        }
        if (villageOptions == "2" && setTool2 == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You approach the local guild hall. The sign on the building reads:");
            Console.WriteLine("\"Fang-jitsu Guild\"");
        }
        if (villageOptions == "2" && setTool2 ==2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You approach the local tavern, the taste of whiskey already on ");
            Console.WriteLine("your lips.");
        }
        if (villageOptions == "0")
        {
            Program.Main();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider saving the random numbers that generate the images to a text file and then reading that text file when you want to load them again.

Writing:

```
try
{
    //Pass the filepath and filename to the StreamWriter Constructor
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\YOUR-PATH-AND-FILENAME-HERE.txt");
    //Write a line of text
    sw.WriteLine("Hello World!!");
    //Write a second line of text
    sw.WriteLine("From the StreamWriter class");
    //Close the file
    sw.Close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
```

Reading:

```
String line;
try
{
    //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\YOUR-PATH-AND-FILENAME-HERE.txt");
    //Read the first line of text
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    //Continue to read until you reach end of file
    while (line != null)
    {
        //write the lie to console window
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        //Read the next line
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
    //close the file
    sr.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
}
```

To read more see: [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/read-write-text-file)

Comment: Interesting and very helpful. Thank you for taking the time to respond instead of just downvoting me for being new at this.